# Is there a good alternative to Facebook's own PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

I've been using Facebook's PHP SDK, but it's buggy and they don't seem to have any interest in fixing [even basic bugs](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/176570592481958).

They don't seem to be interested in doing any serious effort in maintaining it, if they only address bugs based on the number of "me too"s.

Is there some alternative? Any other implementation out there that is being actively maintained in a serious way?

Comment: Can't you just subclass the SDK classes and override any functionality you disagree with the implementation of?

Comment: I can't see that bug report (presumably you need to log into FB for it) but [their blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/) indicates they are squashing a _lot_ of bugs. I don't think many other organisations can compete with that, and fewer (imo) would try. You could do some searching to see if any third party projects are patching/extending the FB libraries, perhaps?

Comment: Could the bug you cite come under the category "duplicate, invalid, or need more information"?

Comment: a session is always initialized to keep login state, prepare for this in your code, then your wont have session already started errors. Swearing at developers will not help.

Comment: Have you thought about forking the project and contributing a fix? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no, opening a session whether or not it is needed is simply wrong. (btw the error is not session already started but headers already sent because output already started). There are cases where you don't need the session to be created, and where the Facebook won't need either, but it calls session_start() anyway, that's plain wrong. The workaround you describe (opening the session myself before) is not always feasible

Comment: @cpilko I would if I had the knowledge and skills to. Or maybe the time. Since I don't, and I detected the bug, I reported it. Usually people developing software are interested in fixing bug. It may take more or less time until somebody fixes the bug, but a bug report usually stays open until it is fixed, or found duplicate or invalid (which no is not the case, @halfer); not closed just because there are bugs that have higher priority.

Comment: Anyway the core of my question was not the rant against FB developers, that was just the background. Mine was a genuine question, is tehre an alternative. I guess the answer is no. I felt the quality of the sdk was so bad (if it has such basic bugs) that it was reasonable to ask whether or not a better alternative existed. I strongly disagree with the decision to close this question as "not constructive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the PHP SDK just use curl.

Have fun!

Incidently, you really shouldn't be outputting before initiating the facebook object. What are you trying to do with the SDK that doesn't involve authentication? And if it does involve authentication, you shouldn't output stuff before you authenticate anyway.

Comment: You really shouldn't be outputting before initiating a session. Hence you are forced to not output before initiatintg the facebook object IF that implies initiating a session. Hehce the facebook object constructor should initiate a session ONLY if it is really needed. And no, it is not always needed. There are things that you can do with a Facebook object that don't involve authentication.

Comment: I guess this answer, rephrased, means "no", there is no other good sdk. So I'll mark it as accepted, also because they have closed this question so even if there was a better answer, it could never be posted